# mySQL AND OR query inconsistant in results returned

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query in php that is set to run hourly by a cron job. Sometimes the results are correct and sometimes I get back a result thats on a different date than being queried. As mysql is being run in a different timezone i am using php `date() time()` to correct the current hour and date. I first use count in mysql to every see if any records exist matching the criteria. And if they do i run the same query and grab the data. I am looking for records that are for the current day. Have a time frame of an hour or hour and a half ahead of the current time and match a couple other parameters being the JobStatus and TechID columns. Sometimes it runs correctly and sometimes I get records showing that are for days ahead. The column for the time in the database is a varchar as I just simply needed the current time to match a string as the appointment is entered into the database as `1PM` or `9:30AM` or whatever time slot was selected on the form in hour or half hour time frames. I have as well added my database structure below too. I have checked the database to see if its corrupt and it checks out fine.
Am I maybe going about this query incorrectly?

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");

$SearchDate = date('Y-m-d', time());

//CURRENT TIME PLUS ONE HOUR
$TimePlusHour = date('gA', strtotime("+1 hours"));

//CURRENT TIME PLUS ONE HOUR PLUS SETTING MINUTES TO HALF HOUR
$Plus30 = date('g:30A', strtotime("+1 hours"));

$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM ServiceTickets WHERE Date=
'".$SearchDate."' AND Time='".$Plus30."' OR Time='".$TimePlusHour."' 
AND JobStatus='1' OR JobStatus='3' AND TechID= '".$TechID."' ";

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM ServiceTickets WHERE Date= '".$SearchDate."' AND
Time='".$Plus30."' OR Time='".$TimePlusHour."' AND JobStatus='1' OR
JobStatus='3' AND TechID= '".$TechID."' ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Database structure

```
CREATE TABLE `ServiceTickets` (
`id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FirstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`LastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`City` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`State` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Zip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Time` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`JobDesc` text,
`JobStatus` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`TechID` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`LastModified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You are assuming the varchar values in the so-called "time" column can be compared reliably to time values established in PHP. Without access to your data we would simply be guessing. btw: naming columns with words used by sql itself (such as "date" and "time") isn't good practice.

Comment: But correct me if I am wrong @Used_By_Already isnt for instance `$TimePlusHour = date('gA', strtotime("+1 hours"));` a string? So if the varchar value in the time column is lets say `9PM` and the `$TimePlusHour` variable is also `9PM` why wouldn't this work? The varchar values in the time column are ONE of many possibilities that are in 1/2 hour increments starting at 8AM then 8:30AM then 9AM and so on and so forth. And the values are selected from a form and only the time frame selected is entered into the column

Comment: IF they match sure. But what guarantees the formats match. Using varchars for any temporal data it fraught with difficulties avoided if you use temporal data types.

Comment: What is your suggestion for a type of column to store the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing your query when calling AND and OR, I would start by putting your OR in parentheses

```
$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM ServiceTickets WHERE Date=
'".$SearchDate."' AND (Time='".$Plus30."' OR Time='".$TimePlusHour."') 
AND (JobStatus='1' OR JobStatus='3') AND TechID= '".$TechID."' ";

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM ServiceTickets WHERE Date= '".$SearchDate."' AND
(Time='".$Plus30."' OR Time='".$TimePlusHour."') AND (JobStatus='1' OR
JobStatus='3') AND TechID= '".$TechID."' ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I am guessing this may be a cause of why its reliability has been sporatic

Comment: Correct, order is important when making queries and when making loner queries it seems to make sense when you read it but doesn't run. AND is always processed before OR unless in parentheses.